# Should I bounty an unfinished answer?

Tags: support, bounty

Should I bounty an unfinished answer when the bounty is nearly expiring and the author seems to be striving to finish it?

Comment: I think that's up to you. If it is something that is important to you, or if you think would be important for a larger audience you should do so.  I don't think most of the people here are going to try to answer something just because it has a bounty, but having a bounty does attract more attention to question, as then it is considered something important to at least one individual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that is really all up to you.

If it is something that is important to you, or if you think would be important for a larger audience you should do so. I don't think most of the people here are going to try to answer something just because it has a bounty, but having a bounty does attract more attention to question, as then it is considered something important to at least one individual.